# Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in mailtest.php

Tags: php, pear, html-email

when I try to send mail with php I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mail' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)
\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\pn\mailtest.php
on line 10
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
  $from="sjoseph@seisystems.com";
  $to="dianahelene@gmail.com";
  $subject="testmail";
  $host="Sei-mail01";

  $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to, 'Subject' => $subject);

  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array ('host' => $host, 'auth' => false));
  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $message);
?>
```

Why is

Comment: You should include the Mail class or paste the whole code.

Comment: [Mail](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) is a native PHP funciton.

Comment: @ficuscr we are dealing with a custom `Mail` _class_, not with the common `mail()` _function_.

Comment: @ficuscr mail() is native php function. Mail is a PEAR module. Is pear availible and activated on your machine?

Comment: @moonwave99 since he labeld this question with PEAR he trys to use the Mail module of PEAR: http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/

Comment: Sorry, totally missed the pear tag.

Answer (score -1):

You need to load the Mail class with `require_once` after the `<?php` tags:

```
require_once 'Mail.php';
```